# How I create a game using my 3d models?

Tags: modeling, export

Ive created a 3d chess board and its pieces in blender and I'm now learning python to create a playable chess game. How do I take what I've made in Blender to use them for the pieces for the game?

Answer (score 1):

Go to *File> Export* and select the file type that you need. Then save the file wherever you want to.

If you want to export individual pieces, select the piece that you want to export and repeat the process above again, but checking the *Selected Only* box.

You can now use the mesh(es) outside of Blender.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! I'll try to link the end result if I manage to finish.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you! I'll try to link the final product if I manage to finish @Najm Hoda